# Problem with checkbox uicomponent, has value doesnt 'check'

Tags: magento2, uicomponent, checkbox

I'm having a trouble with UIComponent. Being precise it's a checkbox.

I'm sure it takes true as a value, but it doesn't appear as a checked one.

So it's propably something wrong with my structure.

```
'is_active' => [
                'arguments' => [
                    'data' => [
                        'config' => [
                            'label' => __('Active'),
                            'dataType' => 'boolean',
                            'formElement' => 'checkbox',
                            'componentType' => 'field',
                            'sortOrder' => 10,
                            'dataScope' => 'is_active',
                            'prefer' => 'toggle',
                            'valueMap' => [
                                'false' => 0,
                                'true' => 1
                            ],
                            'visible' => 1,
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
            ],
```

Comment: Are passing value to the ui-component by its data provider? If yes then share your code of data provider

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand you when you say: "it doesn't appear as checked one."

If you just want it to be checked as default, add this in config:

```
'default' => 1,
```

If that's not the case, please elaborate you question.

Comment: I tried everything including your answer. Gave up and used select instead.

Answer (score 0):

To this day I have no idea what was wrong with a checkbox.
Decided to use Yesno select instead.

```
 /**
 * @var \Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Yesno
 */
protected $yesno;


/**
 * Store constructor.
 * @param \Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Yesno $yesno
 */

 public function __construct(
\Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Yesno $yesno
) {
    $this->yesno = $yesno;
}

...
 'children' => [
            'is_active' => [
                'arguments' => [
                    'data' => [
                        'options' => $this->yesno->toOptionArray(),
                        'config' => [
                            'label' => __('Active'),
                            'dataType' => 'boolean',
                            'formElement' => 'select',
                            'componentType' => 'field',
                            'sortOrder' => 10,
                            'dataScope' => 'is_active',
                            'visible' => 1,
                            'default' => 0,
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
            ],
...
```